# What is file descriptor count in Solr admin UI?

Tags: linux, solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have installed solr 5.2.1 on my linux server. In the UI admin screen under dashboard section, am having a file descriptor count, which is displaying some values to me. So can anyone explain me please what is this file descriptor count.

This is coming only in Linux box, i have installed the same version of solr on windows environment also, but there in the UI screen the file descriptor count is not shown. Is this only  specific to Linux/Unix box?

Thanks 
Adarsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file descriptor is an identifier that refers to an open "file" (where "file" means a file like interface) under a Unix-based operating system. In practice it refers to the number of files that the JVM is holding open / referring to for reading or writing.

Unless you're having a issue with the number of open file descriptors or the number of open files, you can safely ignore this count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)